# Zeroes of real and imaginary parts of $\zeta(1+it)$ separately (if any for $t>1$ say)

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Is anything known about existence and/or location of such zeroes ?

Comment: Haseo Ki and Steven M. Gonek are writing a paper on pair correlation of zeroes of the real part of $\zeta$.

Comment: Very grateful to Sylvain, Stopple, Juan for their authoritative responses.

Comment: May I ask further, the two papers quoted not seeming to go into any detail about the same question for zeta-derivative(1+it), whether similar facts exist for this ? Arises out of question 'where does d/dt(|zeta(1+it)|^2) =0' ?

Comment: @TPTW There are many zeros o f $\zeta'(s)$  with real part $>1$. For each one of these zeros
there are two zeros of $\Re \zeta'(1+it)$ and $\Im\zeta'(1+it)$. For the derivative 
there are parallel real and imaginary lines (to the real axis) separated by $\pi/\log2$. Each one of these parallel  lines gives a zero of $\Re \zeta'(1+it)$ or $\Im\zeta'(1+it)$ respectively.

The x-ray of $\zeta'(s)$ show this, but I have not published this.

Comment: @juan V. many thanks juan. I knew about zeroes zeta-dash from Titchmarsh but yr research on the x-ray quite new to me and v.interesting.

Comment: @juan Are other zeroes of Re and/or Im zeta-dash(1+it) possible, not arising in the way you describe, or does it capture all of them ? How accurate an estimate of their number in [1,T] do you think is possible ?

Answer (score 6):

Theorem 11.9 in Titchmarsh (with $\sigma_0=1$) tells us the values of $\log(\zeta(1+it))$, $t>1$ are everywhere dense in the plane.  Here $\log(\zeta(1+it))$ is defined by continuation along this line from $\sigma>1$.  From this one can see the imaginary part of $\log(\zeta(1+it))$ assumes all integer multiples of $\pi$, and so the imaginary part of $\zeta(1+it)$ is zero infinitely often, and similarly for the real part.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of $\Re\zeta(1+it)=0$ are scarce.  They limit small intervals where
$\Re\zeta(1+it)<0$. The probability in the sense of the limit of the
quotient of the measure of the
set $\{0<t<T: \Re\zeta(1+it)<0\}$ by $T$  is $d(1)=(3.80\pm0.01)\times 10^{-7}$.
R. Brent, J. van de Lune and I show it in https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4910

We compute the first 50 such small intervals the first was situated around $t=682112.9$ and
have length $0.0529$ and the last of these 50 is around $t=8299958.2327$ of length 0.0432.
These are the first 100 zeros of $\Re\zeta(1+it)=0$.

The solutions of $\Im\zeta(1+it)=0$ are at least $cT$ with $c\ge \pi/\log 2$, because there
are real lines parallel to the real axis  that cut the line $\sigma=1$
in the x-ray of $\zeta(s)$ at distances $\pi/\log 2$, and each line gives a zero.
There are other real lines that cut the line $\sigma=1$, they are increasing in number with
$t$.

Apart from this an intuitive idea can be obtained from my paper on x-ray's of $\zeta(s)$
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309433

Comment: Hence the two first solutions of $\Re\zeta(1+it)=0$ are (with 30 decimal digits)
$$t_1=682112.891338239941159556828817,\quad t_2=682112.944250491762439022676048$$